# Finding words in any order with regex

Tags: regex

Considering this entries...

```
red yellow green
yellow green red
green red yellow 
other red yellow 
other green red
```

I can match red, yellow, green in any order (first 3 lines) with:

```
^(^red|^yellow|^green) (red|yellow|green) (red$|yellow$|green$)$
```

Note that i need to find exactly this words, nothing else.
But when i have more words the expression grows a lot.

e.g. (with 4 words)

```
^(^red|^yellow|^green|^black) (red|yellow|green|black) (red|yellow|green|black) (red$|yellow$|green$|black$)$
```

My question is: is there any other simpler way to do this with regex?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: The language is Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can tolerate `red red yellow` (well, I think you can as your regexps match lines like this) then the regexp you need is

```
^(red|yellow|green)( (red|yellow|green))*$
```

You can test it there: https://regex101.com/r/fC3pM3/1 (it also has nice explanation)

Comment: You're right. But i think i am not clear in my example. The strings may not have same prefix, e.g. `red yellow green`.

Comment: Do you mean that word1 is actually "red"? or it should be "red1"?

Comment: Could you please update the question with "real" strings you want to match. Thanks.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot.

Comment: regex101 is an awesome tool. Another alternative `^(red( |)|yellow( |)|green( |)){3}$`. May be useful if you have long strings. Thanks again!